# what does this code line do?

Tags: c, int, sizeof

Hi I am new to C programming can anyone please tell me what this line of code would do:

```
i = (sizeof (X) / sizeof (int))
```

The code actually works with a case statement when it takes a value of bdata and compares it to different cases.

Comment: note that X must be an array declared on the stack for this to work, such that its size is known by the compiler, i.e. don't use it for arrays that have been malloc'd at run-time

Comment: what's the bdata you've mentioned to, in your question?

Comment: After getting your question answered on this website, you should generally accept  the answer that you have found to be most useful and accurate, by clicking the little check mark next to the answer. This will mark your question as "answered" and will display the answer as accepted for everyone to see. It will also award some reputation to you and the person who answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, such a statement is used to calculate the number of elements in an array.

Let's consider an integer array as below:

```
int a[4];
```

Now, when `sizeof(a)` is done it will return `4*4 = 16` as the size. 4 elements and each element is of 4 bytes.

So, when you do `sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)`, you will get 4 which is the length or size of the array.

Answer (score 3):

It computes the number of elements of the array of `int` named `X`.

Answer (score 1):

returns the length of the array X

Answer (score 0):

it computes X's volume in memory divided by the size of an integer in your computer(2 bytes or 4 bytes). If i is integer than it is an integer division. If it is float and X has no even volume, it is real division.

int size can change. X depends on implementation. Division result depends on type of i.

All these means, it computes how many ints fit into X.

Comment: Division result **does not** depend on type of `i`. If needed the result is converted to the type of `i`, after being calculated with the integer type defined by `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides common practice or personal experience there is no reason to think that this `i = (sizeof (X) / sizeof (int))` computes the size of the array X. Most often probably this is the case but in theory X could be of any type, so the given expression would compute the ratio of the sizes of your var X and an int (how much more memory, in bytes, does your X var occupy with respect to an int)

Moreover, if X was a pointer to an array (float* X, the alternate way of declaring arrays in C) this expression would evaluate to 1 on a 32-bit architecture. The pointer would be 4 bytes and the int also 4 bytes => `i = sizeof(X) / sizeof(int) (=1)`